# What is preventing Fluid from working with Safari on iOS and iPadOS?

Tags: fluid-framework

On the FAQ page for Fluid Framework https://fluidframework.com/docs/faq/#what-browsers-are-supported it says that Fluid will only work on Safari for Mac. To me this means that it will not work on iOS or the iPadOS. I don't think I need to explain why this is a problem for adoption.

So, why won't Fluid Framework work on iOS or iPadOS and is there anything that can be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluid Framework does work on iOS and iPadOS, but the framework doesn't get significant test coverage on those browsers. I just tested a few examples on iOS and they worked (DraftJS, brainstorm.) That language in the FAQ should be changed to reflect that there is no automated testing for iOS, but the team intends for Fluid to work.

In fact, Fluid should work in any JavaScript engine. The requirement is that the JS runtime can load the client libraries (written in JS/TS), load the container, and make a connection to the service.

There are even some (fairly hidden) [Node examples](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/examples/hosts/node-host) in the repo, although there isn't automated testing on those examples yet either.

Full Disclosure: I work on the Fluid team